# Selecting AD Users with listed fields empty

Tags: csv, powershell, active-directory

I would like to list all of the users in my domain without specific fields being filled in, In this case, Telephone Number and Title. I have attempted this through Get-ADUser

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Title -NotLike "*" -or Telephone-Number -NotLike "*"} -properties name, emailaddress, office, enabled, telephone-number | select name, emailaddress, office, enabled, telephone number | Export-csv -path c:\temp\cwadtwoexport.csv
```

and

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Title -NotLike "*" -or Telephone-Number -NotLike "*"} -properties name, emailaddress, office, enabled | select name, emailaddress, office, enabled | Export-csv -path c:\temp\cwadexport.csv
```

The second one worked, However it appears to have exported all users in the directory, Regardless of having fields empty or not.

Any advice would be helpful, I am most likely just missing something completely basic.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be an [LDAP filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(|(!(title=*))(!(telephoneNumber=*)))'
```

`(!(attribute=*))` means "where the given attribute does not have any value" (i.e. is null).
`(|...)` combines the nested expressions with a logical OR operation.